# Adding arguments into array by loop

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, directory

I want to create script which will create directories. 
User has to pick how many directories he wants to create, and then has to name those directories.

I already have something like this, but I stuck and don't know how to add arguments into array by loop..

Could you tell me how it should be?

```
#!/bin/bash

read year
read group
read student


subjects=()
for directories in ${subjects[*]}
do
  mkdir -p /home/uczelnia/$year/$group/$student/$directories
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for arrays here. This might be what you are trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -rp "Enter year: " year
IFS= read -rp "Enter group: " group
IFS= read -rp "Enter student: " student

read -rp "Enter number of dirs: " number

for (( i=1; i<=number; i++ )); do
    IFS= read -rp "Enter folder #$i: " folder
    mkdir -p "/home/uczelnia/$year/$group/$student/$folder"
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's something what I wanted to create

Answer (score 0):

To have the user enter subjects and save them in array `subjects`, run:

```
echo "Enter subjects, one per line, type Ctrl-D when done:"
readarray -t subjects
```

Running the above code and entering three subject:

```
Enter subjects, one per line, type Ctrl-D when done:
Math
History
Biology
```

(At the new line after biology, we can't see it but the user typed Ctrl-D.)

We can verify that `subjects` is indeed the array we want by examining it with `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p subjects
declare -a subjects=([0]=$'Math\n' [1]=$'History\n' [2]=$'Biology\n')
```

#### Aside

When you use reference variables, they should be in double-quotes to prevent word-splitting and pathname expansion.  Thus, replace:

```
for directories in ${subjects[*]}
do
  mkdir -p /home/uczelnia/$year/$group/$student/$directories
done
```

With:

```
for directories in "${subjects[@]}"
do
  mkdir -p "/home/uczelnia/$year/$group/$student/$directories"
done
```

#### Whole script

```
read -p "Enter year: " year
read -p "Enter group: " group
read -p "Enter student: " student
echo "Enter subjects, one per line, type Ctrl-D when done:"
readarray -t subjects
for directories in "${subjects[@]}"
do
  mkdir -p "/home/uczelnia/$year/$group/$student/$directories"
done
```